# Vue.JS - Both 'history' and 'hash' router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm working on a Vue.Js site and using the Vue-router default mode "hash". So the site URL is something like that:

```
www.mysite.com/#/Home
```

This site is already being linked by some mobile apps, and I can't change them. But I have a new requirement and I need to change the URLs to remove the hash (#) from the URL. So I changed the Vue-router mode to "history" and now my site is working without the hash. Like that:

```
www.mysite.com/Home
```

The problem is that using the history mode the URL with the hash (#) doesn't work. But for compatibility with the mobile apps that link the site with hash, I still need to make the URL with the hash works.

QUESTION:

How can I use the Vue-router history mode and also keep the URLs with hash working?

I tried the following way at the router/index.js file:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
        path: '/Home',
        name: 'Home1',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/#/Home',
        name: 'Home2',
        component: Home
    },
    ...
]})
```

Using this configuration the URL www.mysite.com/Home works, but the URL www.mysite.com/#/Home doesn't work.

Comment: Question was [answered in the vuejs forums](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-history-mode-with-support-for-legacy-hash-mode-urls/38073/2)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy that worked thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm answering my own question based on the comment of the @Ohgodwhy and [a question/answer](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-history-mode-with-support-for-legacy-hash-mode-urls/38073/2) from the vue.js forum that was answered by [@nathany](https://forum.vuejs.org/u/nathany).

The solution is to remove the has (#) from the URLs that have the hash, and redirecting it to the URL without the hash. It can be done at the method router.beforeEach().

My router/index.js was something like that:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/Home'

export default new Router({
      mode: 'history',
      routes: [
        {
            path: '/Home',
            name: 'Home',
            component: Home
        },
      ],
})
```

Then I changed to:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/Home'

var router = new Router({
      mode: 'history',
      routes: [
        {
            path: '/Home',
            name: 'Home',
            component: Home
        },
      ],
})
export default router;

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // Redirect if fullPath begins with a hash (ignore hashes later in path)
    if (to.fullPath.substr(0,2) === "/#") {
        const path = to.fullPath.substr(2);
        next(path);
        return;
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work anymore in current version or current browser. I'm not sure which is responsible for that. Fullpath is without "#".

Answer (score 1):

For me I just needed to route external legacy links to current history-mode.

In App.vue mounted:

```
if (location.hash) {
  location.replace(location.hash.replace('#', ''))
}
```